# Molecular diffusivity of a three-component mixture

Tags: molecular-structure, mixtures, diffusion, gas-phase-chemistry

I usually used a following expression by Fuller & Schettler & Giddings to predict molecular diffusivities of binary mixtures:

\begin{equation}
D_i = \dfrac{1\cdot 10^{-4}\left(0.00143\cdot T^{1.75}\right)}{\left(P\cdot {M_{ib}^{1/2}}\cdot \left(\left(\sum \nu_i\right)^{1/3} + \left(\sum \nu_b\right)^{1/3}\right) \right)^2}
\end{equation}

(where $P$ is a pressure, $T ...$ temperature, $\nu ...$ molecular constant, $M ...$ molecular weight) as it gives a decent accuracy for most of the binary mixtures.

There are other formulas to predict a diffusivity, but to my knowledge, all them are for a binary mixtures.

What would you recommend for a molecular diffusivity prediction of a three component mixture of $\ce{N2}$, $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{O2}$?